# How to insert Bold tags into a template literal string in react and typescrip

Tags: reactjs, typescript, patternfly

I have a form that appears when a button is pressed, the heading of the form will be different for each item in a list, I can remove these items. I would like the name of the item in the form heading to be bold but I am struggling to implement this correctly

my form looks like

```
render(): React.ReactNode {

 return (
  <FormGroup
    fieldId='example-form
    helperText={`do you want to delete <b>${this.props.item.name}</b>?`
    >
    </FormGroup>
   )
  }
```

this currently prints out the `<b>` tags. I have tried assigning `this.props.item.name` to a variable as a string and using bold() on that but it didn't work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It would hep If you included where the FormGroup component comes from for better understanding of the helperText prop

Comment: The FormGroup is a patternfly4 component and is just being returned here when a button is activated in another component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't embed html in a string, which is a security feature of React to prevent cross site scripting when displaying user provided content.

But, what you actually have here is JSX!

So change the `helperText` type to `React.ReactNode` and now you can pass in a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) like so:

```
<FormGroup
  fieldId='example-form'
  helperText={
    <>
      do you want to delete <b>{this.props.item.name}</b>?
    </>
  }
/>
```

Comment: where exactly are you advising this to be created, inside render and before return, it breaks completely there

Comment: As a prop. I've updated my answer to include that part

Comment: your answer works, I didn't realise I could pass in the <> </> tags like that and thought I could only do them outside the {}. I need to learn more about them.

Answer (score 1):

Passing of HTML tag inside template literals is not allowed. It will render your HTML tag as a string. To solve it, you can create a JSX variable for your help text and pass that to your `helperText` prop in `FormGroup` element.

```
render(): React.ReactNode {
 const helperText = <>do you want to delete <b>{this.props.item.name}</b></>;

 return (
   <FormGroup
    fieldId='example-form'
    helperText={helperText}
   >
   </FormGroup>
  )
}
```

Comment: when I tried this method, I get an error when it tries to compile, complaining that the item is undefined

Comment: @Aindriu Well, that's up to you to pass in an `item` prop.